# Pyqt5 concurrent file operations with concurrent.futures module

Tags: concurrency, pyqt

I'm currently running on one python Gui development based on Pyqt5. There is quite a lot of file system related operations such as copy, move and delete. I tried to enhance the performance of these operations by utilizing concurrent.futures module and experimented on both Threadpoolexecutor and Processpoolexecutor. However, neither of them could give me a unblocking gui which would be able to go on with user interaction after I submitted the file operations to the pool. These submitted operations are simply static methods of native python classes. I also added callbacks through the Future objects returned by submissions, which are the instance methods of one qt class and which did get called when the corresponding submitted job had completed. 
Just unable to figure out a way to solve the problem of freezed ui(even just for seconds' duration) Could anybody help?

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

class ArchiveResManager:
    def __init__(self, resource_dir):
        self._path_reference_dir = resource_dir

def get_resource_list(self):
    return tuple(
        de.path for de in os.scandir(self._path_reference_dir) if de.is_file()
        )

def add_callback_resource_added(fn):
    self._callback_on_resource_added = fn

def add_resources(self, resources: iter):
    src_paths = tuple(p for p in resources)
    dest_paths = tuple(self._get_dest_path(p) for p in resources)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(2) as executor:
        exe.submit(
            ArchiveResManager._do_resource_operations,
            src_paths,
            dest_paths
        ).add_done_callback(self._on_resource_added)

@staticmethod
def _do_resource_operations(src_paths, dest_paths):
    added_items = list()
    for src_path, dest_path in zip(src_paths, dest_paths):
        shutil.copyfile(
            src_path, dest_path
        )
        added_items.append(dest_path)
    return added_items

def _on_resource_added(self, future):
    if future.done():
        if self._callback_on_resource_added:
            self._callback_on_resource_added(future.result())

# This model class is bound to a instance of QListView in the QDialog of my project
class ArchiveModel(QAbstractListModel):

def __init__(self, archive_dir, parent):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self._archive_manager = ArchiveResManager(archive_dir)
    self._archive_manager.add_callback_resource_added(self._on_archive_operations_completed)
    self._archive_items = self._archive_manager.get_resource_list()

def _on_archive_operations_completed(self, result_list):
    last_row = self.rowCount() - 1
    self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), last_row, last_row + len(result_list))
    self._archive_items.extend(result_list)
    self.endInsetRows()
```

Comment: I just edited the question with the snippet from my project.

Comment: I confess I wasn't quite following the rules of SO, but to build a minimal, complete and  verifiable example might also prove to be helpful by itself for my grasp of the problem. Thanks for your suggestion and tips on using signals.